# PDFJS: Rendering PDF on canvas

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas, pdf.js

I am trying to render pdf file on canvas.

Framework is Nuxt.js (Vue)

Finally, I rendered pdf on canvas, but something is strange. Zoomed pdf was rendered.

I tried to change scale and other values, but the result was same.

How can I fix this?

Please check my attached images.

This is excepted pdf.

[image]

And my result is as following: (Current scale value is 1.5)

[image]

This is my some code to render pdf.

```
<script>
export default {
  props: ["page", "scale"],
  mounted() {
    this.drawPage();
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.destroyPage(this.page);
  },
  methods: {
    drawPage() {
      if (this.renderTask) return;

      const { viewport } = this;
      const canvasContext = this.$el.getContext("2d");

      const renderContext = { canvasContext, viewport };

      this.renderTask = this.page.render(renderContext);
      this.renderTask.promise.then(() => this.$emit("rendered", this.page));
      this.renderTask.promise.then(/* */).catch(this.destroyRenderTask);
    },
    destroyPage(page) {
      if (!page) return;

      page._destroy();
      if (this.renderTask) this.renderTask.cancel();
    },

    destroyRenderTask() {
      if (!this.renderTask) return;

      this.renderTask.cancel();
      delete this.renderTask;
    },
  },
  render(h) {
    const { canvasAttrs: attrs } = this;
    return h("canvas", { attrs });
  },
  created() {
    this.viewport = this.page.getViewport({
      scale: this.scale,
    });
  },
  computed: {
    canvasAttrs() {
      let { width, height } = this.viewport;
      [width, height] = [width, height].map((dim) => Math.ceil(dim));

      const style = this.canvasStyle;

      return {
        style,
        class: "pdf-page",
      };
    },

    canvasStyle() {
      const {
        width: actualSizeWidth,
        height: actualSizeHeight,
      } = this.actualSizeViewport;
      const pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
      const [pixelWidth, pixelHeight] = [
        actualSizeWidth,
        actualSizeHeight,
      ].map((dim) => Math.ceil(dim / pixelRatio));
      return `width: ${pixelWidth}px; height: ${pixelHeight}px;`;
    },

    actualSizeViewport() {
      return this.viewport.clone({ scale: this.scale });
    },
  },
  watch: {
    page(page, oldPage) {
      this.destroyPage(oldPage);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: As you can see above images, the zoomed pdf was rendered. I can't understand the reason of that.

Comment: Without seeing your code, we would only be guessing as well. Please include a small, working sample of code that produces that error.

Comment: @Tigger, Thanks for your reply, I have attached my code that render pdf. Please check that.